# How to import CSV into SQL Server and Removing characters and unwanted text

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hi I am trying to upload this csv file into sql server but there is a lot of unwanted text and characters that is generated on the csv creation from another application.

I think this is more complicated than a row delimiter and column delimiter.

Here is an example of the csv that I would like to upload:

```
"Report Name: My Keyword Performance Report"
"Report Time: 6/10/2015"
"Time Zone: (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada); Tijuana"
"Last Completed Available Day: 6/11/2015 7:00:00 PM (GMT)"
"Last Completed Available Hour: 6/11/2015 7:00:00 PM (GMT)"
"Report Aggregation: Daily"
"Report Filter: "
"Potential Incomplete Data: true"
"Rows: 123"

"GregorianDate","AccountId","CampaignId","Keyword","KeywordId","Device type","BiddedMatchType","Clicks","Impressions","Ctr","AverageCpc","Spend","QualityScore"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck","7695873172","Computer","Exact","4","9","44.44","0.66","2.64","10"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck","7695873172","Smartphone","Exact","2","3","66.67","0.23","0.45","10"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck parts","7695873174","Computer","Exact","5","11","45.45","0.87","4.37","10"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck parts","7695873174","Smartphone","Exact","1","1","100.00","0.14","0.14","10"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck","7695873185","Computer","Exact","289","565","51.15","0.07","21.41","10"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck","7695873185","Smartphone","Exact","64","152","42.11","0.06","3.56","10"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck","7761199395","Computer","Phrase","27","105","25.71","0.44","11.98","10"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck","7761199395","Smartphone","Phrase","4","23","17.39","0.53","2.13","10"
"6/10/2015","8455565","110123754","truck austin","7695873173","Computer","Exact","0","2","0.00","0.00","0.00","10"

"Ã‚Â©2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. "
```

How would I upload this information to SQL Server?  I have no idea how to remove the " and the top 9 rows as well as the bottom row that contains

> ```
> "Ã‚Â©2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. "
> ```

Any suggestions or code that could help me?

Comment: Are you importing via UI or through a script?

Comment: I want to import through vb.net

Comment: Oh! ok ok, if it's through a program then things are a bit "easier" you have control of the content of the csv (which is just a text file with some format)
You can remove lines easily, replace the " with an empty string and finally remove the last line without much trouble. I'm not an experienced VB programmer but as soon as I have some code I will post it here

Answer (score 0):

How about: create a very simple `#temp` table:

```
CREATE TABLE #raw_data
                   (GregorianDate   VARCHAR(500),
                    AccountId       VARCHAR(500),
                    CampaignId      VARCHAR(500),
```

... and so on, you get the idea - it's just a dumb container for strings, not a real data structure. Then:

```
BULK INSERT #raw_data FROM 'myfilepath.csv' WITH
     (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Then:

```
DELETE #raw_data WHERE QualityScore IS NULL
```

And what you'll be left with is the data you want. From there, insert it into the table(s) you want it stored in.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. The part where I check if the string has the "Microsoft" substring in order to ignore is not elegant at all, but does the job. I encourage you to find a better way :)

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(textBoxFileName.Text)
    Dim RowData As String
    Dim counter As Integer = 1

    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        RowData = objReader.ReadLine().Replace("""", "")

        If (counter <= 9) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        Else
            If (RowData.IndexOf("Microsoft") = -1) Then
                RowData.Replace("""", "")
                MessageBox.Show(RowData & " :: This is the data from the line. What to do with it is up to you :)")
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```